# How do I count number of instances of an output in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

**TL;DR**

The idea is :

```
awk '{
    IP[$1]++;
  }
  END {
    for(var in IP) 
      print IP[var]
  }
}' getline < sockstat | awk '{print $2 "@" $3}' | grep -v '^PROCESS@PID'
```

I want to count the number of instance of every block in the output from -> 
sockstat | awk '{print $2 "@" $3}' | grep -v '^PROCESS@PID'

Which looks like:

```
ubuntu-geoip-pr@2382
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
chrome@2453
rhythmbox@4759
rhythmbox@4759
rhythmbox@4759
```

Finally, I want to get the output as:

```
1
8
3
```

This corresponds to the number of occurrences of each of the items in the previous output.

**Problem in full:**

The *sockstat* command outputs the info for some networking stats for the localhost. I first print out a single key from the second and third columns from the output (PROCESS and PID, respectively), in the form PROCESS@PID. Then, I want to calculate the frequency of each unique key from that output. One way to do this is to use the awk getline structure, but that seems works for files, and I have not been able to make it pull input directly from the above command.

I do not want to use temporary files, as that takes away the elegance of the solution.

Comment: If you supply a filename like `getline`, `awk` won't read its standard input (the file `sockstat`).  You have a case-sensitivity problem in the first script (two occurrences of `Ip`, one of `IP`).  Since the output of the first script is one field, the second `awk` script can't be reading fields 2 and 3.  What constitutes a 'block' in the output? What does your data actually look like?  What are you expecting as output?

Comment: Fixed the case. Typo, my bad.

Comment: wouldn't `uniq -c` be a better solution here?

Comment: You good sir, just solved the entire issue. I didn't knwo `uniq` took arguments. Adding that as an answer for documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sockstat | awk '{print $2 "@" $3}' | grep -v '^PROCESS@PID' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: The input to `uniq -c` must be sorted; it is not clear that the input there is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sockstat | grep -v PROCESS | awk '{key=$2"@"$3; count[key]++} END {for ( key in count ) { print key" "count[key]; } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your command:

```
sockstat | awk 'NR>1 { a[$2 "@" $3]++ } END { for (i in a) print a[i], i }'
```

If you just want the counts, simply edit the print statement:

```
sockstat | awk 'NR>1 { a[$2 "@" $3]++ } END { for (i in a) print a[i] }'
```